# How do I refresh Authorization policies in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API after application has started

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API in which I am using custom authorization policies. For applying these policies, I have my owner authorization handler, which is looking at the custom policy requirements and checking it with the validated access token, and applies the authorization. What I am trying to find out is how do I refresh the policy definition after the application has started.

For example, my controller will just have the annotation `Authorize("ElevatedUser")`. But the policy requirement will say `ElevatedUser` means a user has either Role1 or Role2. The user role information is coming as part of the claims in the access token. Now lets my definition of `ElevatedUser` is extended to additional 2 roles - Role3 and Role4 and I update the policy configuration externally. Let's also assume that I have some kind of custom configuration provider implemented, which will let me pull this policy information periodically (say every 30 or 60 minutes).

In my current code, I am registering the policy at application startup and I would have pulled this policy configuration as part of my application startup. Now if the policy configuration is updated: how to update or refresh my existing policy so that application now has visibility to the updated policy definition with 4 roles, instead of 2 roles?

Thanks!

Comment: You  cannot register policy after application has started, so how you refresh  existing policy ?

Comment: I am not looking to register new policy. All I need to do is change the value of the policy requirement that is attached to the registered policy. Since I have my own custom auth policy handler and provider, when I have to validate the policy, the handler gets a copy of the requirement (in the HandleRequirementAsync method of policy handler, we get AuthorizationContext and Requirement as parameters) against which policy is being applied. So I am trying to figure out how to update the policy requirement information. That will allow me to meet this requirement.